# changing the color of the text using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnhighlight").click(function () {
                alert("yes");
                var htext = $("#txthighlighttext").val();
                $("#lstCodelist option").each(function () {
                    var sp = $(this).text();
                    var sp1 = sp.split(' ');
                    $.each(sp1, function (i, l) {
                        if (l == htext) {
                            l.css('color', 'yellow');
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        });
```

var x = "hello world";
I need to change the text color on l. that is suppor I got the text from the string "hello".
css(
Can I do `l.('color', 'yellow');` I am getting javascript error.

if I do like this `$(this).css('color', 'yellow');` Nothing happening.

thanks

Comment: `sp1` is a string, not a DOM object. `.text()` returns a string, so you're iterating over a array of strings, not DOM objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

`$(l).css('color', 'yellow');`

Edit:

Ok...you are working with strings and not actual DOM elements.  My suggestion is to dynamically place `l` into an element like `<span>` and apply the CSS to that and then replace the original text in the DOM.  I actually did something similar to this a while back:

http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/03/07/how-to-find-and-replace-text-dynamically-via-javascript/

I'm not saying this is the perfect solution but it will lead you down the right path.

Comment: Are you sure that `if` statement is testing `true`?  Try placing the following `alert` inside that `if` statement and make sure it is executing: `alert("htext:" + htext + " l:" + l);`

Comment: Yes I put the alert in the my if condition I am perfectly getting l value. thanks

Comment: Ah! I see what is going on. This is a string you are working with. You will need to dynamically place this into a `<span>` or something and then add that to the DOM (replacing the original text) and then add the styling.

Answer (score 0):

`l` in is the element you are iterating, wrap it inside the `$` and you are good to go

try

```
$.each(sp1, function (i, l) {
if (l == htext) {
  $(l).css('color', 'yellow');
}
```

Comment: No this is not working for me. its not changing the text color.

Comment: that is probably because `l` is not a DOM element as @Alex mentioned in the comments

Answer (score 0):

will something like this work? (untested)

```
     $('<span>', {
            'style': 'color:yellow',
            html: l
        }).appendTo('#divName');
```

Comment: this example will create a new span with the text appended to another element.  I guesse this might not really work for what you are trying to do and I don't have time right now to work on it any further.. but you probably DO need a new dom element created for the text whose color you want to change... perhaps you can demolish the contents of the option and replace them with a new span for each word?  And if its the text you are looking for, set the style like in my example

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned `l` is not a dom element, which means you just need to "push" it inside the next each loop.

```
$("#lstCodelist option").each(function () {
    var sp = this; //or $(this) and then you do sp.css('color', 'yellow');
    var sp1 = $(this).split(' ');

    $.each(sp1, function (i, l) {
       if (l == htext) {
           $(sp).css('color', 'yellow');
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is not working realshadow its saying object error in var sp1 = $(this).split(' ');